# Enterprise iOS app in Guided Access

Tags: ipad, enterprise, guided-access

We have alot of iPads on different locations, running an enterprise app in Guided Access. Is it possible to auto update the app, our remote access the iPad to update?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both.

There are remote management platforms that allow you to manage your iOS devices; change passwords, lock a device if it gets stolen, etc.  They need to be connected to the internet for this to work though, either through 3G/4G or wifi.

You can also set an iOS device to auto-download updates when they become available.